# error while importing an sqlto phpMyAdmin db

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to import an SQL file to my phpMyAdmin database, the file contains tables about a restaurant application and a table about the admin login, but I have 2 unexpected errors, I really don't see what is exactly wrong with that?. here is the error message:

Static analysis:
2 errors were found during analysis.

1. An opening bracket followed by a set of values was expected. (near "CREATE" at position 285)
2. Unexpected token. (near "CREATE" at position 285)

SQL query:

```
-- -- Déchargement des données de la table `operation` -- 

    INSERT INTO `operation` (`numop`, `numcp`, `prenom`, `nom`, `type`, `numcp2`, `mentant`, `date`) VALUES 

-- -------------------------------------------------------- -- 
-- Structure de la table `reclamation` -- 

    CREATE TABLE `reclamation` (
    `numrec` int(11) NOT NULL
    ,`id` varchar(8) NOT NULL
    ,`prenom` varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,`nom` varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,`text` text NOT NULL
    ,`date` datetime NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ;
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `reclamation` (
> `numrec` int(11) NOT NULL,
> `id` varchar(8) NO' at line 14

```
CREATE TABLE `reclamation` (
  `numrec` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: the create table has np error it is the insert that misses data

Comment: You have nothing after `VALUES` in the `INSERT` query. Also, the file needs `;` between the queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are no values after `VALUES` in operation insertion query.

This error points on create because this is the next to the insertion and it expected to be values but actually is `CREATE ...`

It seems the values cutted off, make sure to separate between queries with `;`

```
INSERT INTO `operation` (`numop`, `numcp`, `prenom`, `nom`, `type`, `numcp2`, `mentant`, `date`) VALUES
```

---

-- Structure de la table `reclamation` --

```
CREATE TABLE `reclamation` (
`numrec` int(11) NOT NULL
,`id` varchar(8) NOT NULL
,`prenom` varchar(30) NOT NULL
,`nom` varchar(30) NOT NULL
,`text` text NOT NULL
,`date` datetime NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ;
```